# If $|F| = 8$ and $K$ is a subfield, show that $K = F$ or $K = \{0, 1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $K$ be a subring of a field $F$. If $|F| = 8$ and $K$ is a subfield, show that $K = F$ or $K = \{0, 1\}$. [Hint: Lagrange].

Lagrange's Theorem: If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$

**I** Then $|H|$ divides $|G|$

**II** $\frac{|G|}{|H|}=|G:H|$ is the index of $H$ in $G$

So by Lagrange's Theorem, $|K|$ divides $8$ and so $|K|=2,4,$ or $8$. If $|K|=2$ then $K=\{0,1\}$ and if $|K|=8$ then $K=F$. So I just need to show if $|K|=4$ then $K$ can not be a field. I am not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Furthermore, $|K^\times|$ divides $|F^\times|$, so $|K|-1$ divides $8-1=7$. Since $7$ is prime, there are only two subfields, $F$ and $\mathbb F_2$.

Answer (score 3):

$F$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$. Therefore there exists some $n \geq 0$ such that $|K|^n = |F| = 8$. Thus $|K| \in \{2,8\}$. The result follows immediately from this.